# Calculate the convergence of MMSE

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

$$X(n) = \mathcal{N}(0, 1), n=1,2,...$$
$$N(n) = \mathcal{N}(0.3, 1), n=1,2,...$$
$$X(n) \text{ and } N(n) \text{ are both i.i.d.}$$
$$\hat{X}(n)=\frac{1}{5}(4X(n)+2N(n)-0.6)$$
$$f(k)= \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k}[(X(n)-\hat{X}(n))^2]$$
Prove: 
1: $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}f(k)=0.2$ 
2: $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}f(k)$ is almost surely convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct application of the strong law of large numbers for the random variable $(X(1) - \hat{X}(1))^2$.

$$E[(X(1)-\hat{X}(1))^2] = \text{Var}((X(1) - \hat{X}(1)) = (1/5)^2 + (2/5)^2 = 0.2.$$

Comment: where did you get that $E[A^2] = Var(A)$? I can't seem to find this equality anywhere?

Comment: oh never mind, i got it.. $Var(A) = E[A^2]-E[A]^2$ and in this case $E[A]=0$